# How to make a network folder that is only accessible on certain PCs

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, network-shares, windows-domain

Is there a way to make a network folder that can only be accessed on certain PCs instead of user accounts?

Basically, my school uses domain login for every computer lab in the district, meaning that we don't have local accounts. I'm working on a project that requires a folder that will be synced between about 8 PCs in the same room. They are all connected with CAT5E network switches that go throughout the room, allowing transfers fast enough that the hard drive is the read and write limit.

The issue is, currently, I can only either share to individual user accounts or everyone in the district. Using individual user sharing means that if I am not present, the pool system does not work and others will not be able to use the render farm setup. I need to make the folder show up for any user using the specific PCs so that anyone who is signed in to the pooled PCs can use them.

Does anyone know how to do this? The IT is incompetent enough at my school, so I would appreciate ways that I didn't have to submit a request for Administrator approval to install on the PC, but I am willing to.

Comment: Create a security group in Active Directory, and add the computers in question to that SG. Then, grant access to the file/folder to that SG?

Comment: Thank you, I will try that tomorrow when I'm in that class!